# Big-O for public key encryption

Tags: cryptography, big-o, public-key-encryption

I have been searching for a few days now, but I cannot find a big-O notation algorithm for encrypting, decrypting, or attempting to break an encrypted file (brute force) making use of public key encryption. I am attempting to determine the big-O notation of an idea I have developed that makes heavy use of public key encryption.

What are these Big-O algorithms as related to public key encryption:

A) Encrypt a file made up of N characters with an L length key

B) Decrypt that same file

C) A typical brute force algorithm to break an encrypted file with N characters and with a maximum key length of L

Any included Big-O notations for more efficient algorithms for breaking the encryption would be appreciated. Also, reference to wherever this material can be found.

Sorry to ask a question that I really should be able to find on my own, but I haven't managed to come across what I am looking for.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that all operations will be O(N).  In the case of A) and B), N represents the length of data acted upon.  In the case of C, N represents the permutations of a key of length L.

Comment: I would love a reference to some documentation or something, if at all possible. And an actual answer so I can accept it. ;)

Comment: Also, it would surprise me if the encryption/decryption was only order N. My understanding of general secure cryptography (which isn't extensive; i may be wrong) is that each encrypted character is dependent upon multiple characters in the original file (not a character to character conversion or simple ASCII manipulation). Wouldn't this imply at least an order N*log(N) algorithm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Standard public/private key algorithms are almost never used on large inputs, as the security properties of these algorithms are generally not suitable for bulk encryption. The most common configuration is to use a public/private key algorithm to encrypt a small (constant-size, usually 128 - 256 bit) key, then use that key for a symmetric encryption algorithm.

That being said, I'll use RSA as a test case for the rest of the questions:

A/B) Setting aside key generation, RSA encrypts and decrypts in `O(n)` for the size of the message. (Note that all messages must be the size of the key, so smaller messages are padded and larger messages must be broken up.) The exact speed of encryption/decryption depends on the algorithms used by your RSA implementation, but it's polynomial in key size:

> http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/rsa_key_length.shtml

C) Given a public key, RSA can be cracked by factoring the public key, which is currently best accomplished using [GNFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve) (which is `O(exp((7.1 b)^1/3 (log b)^1/3))`). I don't believe there's much work on cracking RSA based on encrypted data, as the public key is a much more useful target.

Comment: If RSA would be exponential in key size, it would be much too slow (and not much slower than brute-forcing). The sentence highlighted on the linked page looks more like between quadratic (this would be factor 4) and cubic (factor eight).

Comment: duskwuff 19:07 Oct 4 2011 "GNFS [is] O(exp((7.1 b)^1/3 (log b)^1/3)))"

Apologies if obtuse, but what is 'b'? E.g., the value of the public key, or the length of the public key in bits (which the question above denotes with 'L'), or Something Completely Different?

Comment: From the wikipedia page, pretty sure `b` is the length of the key in bits. It matches up fairly well with the L-Notation complexity *n* variable. But I would also like confirmation. @TomRoche